# Get data to/from secondary PHP file - works with some data, not with other

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a SPA (react) that is uses  PHP calls to connect to a MongoDB.

Works great.

However, due to 'rules' I need to serve the javascript files from a different server -- a server that supports neither MongoDB nor MongoDB php client.  Let's call this server, SERVER_A.

Let's call the server hosting the MongoDB PHP client and the MongoDB, SERVER_B.  ('B' for 'backend'... :) )

The solution, I believe, was to build a php 'middleman' on SERVER_A that simply passes data on to SERVER_B.  Research shows me that `file_get_contents` is the tool for this.

So I take my original known-working PHP file, I put it on SERVER_B and rename it to "mongoPatch_backend.php".

```
<?php
$user = "xxxx";
$pwd = 'xxx';
$filter = [];

if (isset($_REQUEST['needleKey'])) {
    $needleKey = $_REQUEST['needleKey'];
    $needle = $_REQUEST['needle'];
    $filter = [$needleKey => $needle];
} 

$newData = $_REQUEST['newData'];

$filter = ['x' => ['$gt' => 1]];
$options = [
    'projection' => ['_id' => 0],
    'sort' => ['x' => -1],
];

$bson = MongoDB\BSON\fromJSON($newData);
$value = MongoDB\BSON\toPHP($bson);

$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://${user}:${pwd}@SERVER_B:27017");


$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$bulk->update(
    [$needleKey => $needle],
    ['$set' => $value],
    ['multi' => false, 'upsert' => true]
);

$results = $manager->executeBulkWrite('sedwe.users', $bulk);

var_dump($results);
?>
```

On SERVER_A I then make a new file, dbPatch.php, like so:

```
<?php
$API = "https://SERVER_B/php/mongoPatch_backend.php?";

if (isset($_REQUEST['needleKey'])) {
    $needleKey = $_REQUEST['needleKey'];
    $needle = $_REQUEST['needle'];
    $filter = [$needleKey => $needle];
} 

$newData = $_REQUEST['newData'];

$postData = "needleKey=".urlencode($needleKey);
$postData .= "&needle=".urlencode($needle);
$postData .= "&newData=".urlencode($newData);

// echo $API.$postData;
$data = file_get_contents($API.$postData);

echo $data;
?>
```

But when I call it, I get nothing echo'd back out of $data.

Any idea why?   Remember, the exact same call directly to mongoPatch_backend.php works just fine (but it's a CORS call, so it's not a valid option).

**So here is what I've tried:**

First, to ensure my AJAX call was still working, I spit out the response to the console.   I get nothing.
So I changed the last line of the middleman (dbPatch.php) to `echo "Hello World"` instead of `echo $data` and received "Hello World" on the console as expected.

Next, I then changed the last line of my middleman (dbPatch.php) back to `echo $data` and tried reducing the 'backend' to a simple `<?php echo "Hello Back World"; ?>` and got nothing on the console.

Next, I go to https://SERVER_B/php/mongoPatch_backend.php in a browser ... and I'm greeted with "Hello Back World" as expected in the browser.

... which leads me to believe something is up with the transferring of info from server to server.  Logical call, eh?

Unfortunately, when I try the same thing with just a 'fetch' command, it works perfectly fine:

Here is my 'middleman' (dbFetch.php) script on SERVER_A:

```
<?php
$API = "https://SERVER_B/php/mongoFetch_backend.php?";

$collection = $_REQUEST['collection'];
$postData = "collection=".urlencode($collection);

$needleID = $_REQUEST['needleID'];
$postData .= "&needleID=".urlencode($needleID);

$data = file_get_contents($API.$postData);

echo $data;
?>
```

And this is the file on the backend, SERVER_B:

```
<?php

$user = "xxxx";
$pwd = 'xxxx';
$filter = [];

if (isset($_REQUEST['needleID'])) {
    $needleID = $_REQUEST['needleID'];
    $filter = ['id'=> $needleID];
} 

if (isset($_REQUEST['collection'])) {
    $collection = $_REQUEST['collection'];
} 

//Manager Class
$connection = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://${user}:${pwd}@SERVER_B:27017");

// Query Class
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter);

$rows = $connection->executeQuery("db_name.$collection", $query);

// Convert rows to Array and send result back to client
$rowsArr = $rows->toArray();
echo json_encode($rowsArr);
?>
```

Huzzah, this works! ... and it's also proof there doesn't appear to be a problem with the server-to-server communication.

So back to ground zero.

I then go with a very simple `newData` value -- shorter, but same general layout - stringified json.  It works!  The data ends up in the database.

So I'm forced to think something is wrong with the data in `newData`  (which is only a few hundred lines of stringified JSON made like this: `encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(newData))`.   But, this bears repeating: this works if I skip the middleman.

... and that puts me at a loss.  PHP isn't something I understand well... can you help?

EDIT to answer comment:
When I call mongoPatch_backend.php directly on SERVER_B it works (as stated above).  I had it echo the `$newData` and it spits out a stringified JSON version of the variable (not URLencoded).
When I call dbPatch.php, it does not give me anything that was passed back from mongoPatch_backend.
As I said in the OP, if I modify mongoPatch_backend.php to do nothing other than echo "hellow world" I am still unable to log it to console when calling it via the above dbPatch.php file.

EDIT:  I also tried putting the two PHP files on the same server and am getting the same results.  (ie: both the dbPatch.php and mongoPatch.php files are in the same directory on the same server)

EDIT2:  I have done a var_dump from the middleman and I get standard-looking human-readable stringified text back.
I do the same `var_dump($_REQUEST['newData']);` in the backend file and I get nothing back.

Comment: Did you log and compare `$_REQUEST['newData']` on SERVER_A and on SERVER_B?

Comment: Do you mean when called directly?  (I don't know how to log PHP stuff other than write it to console after it returns from the AJAX call)  I can do that and update the above.

Comment: I updated the original post

Comment: I meant to do for example `var_dump($_REQUEST['newData'])` on both servers and compare results.
Btw did you try to replace `file_get_contents` with `curl`?